# How to cache or reuse MongoDB database connection in Serverless (AWS Lambda) application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm building a Serverless application using **NodeJS** and using **MongoDB**. I noticed that a lot of connections are created when handling a request. So I came up with a caching mechanism but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code.

**Connection file**

```
'use strict';

const connectDatabase = mongoClient => mongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_STRING, { poolSize: 10 });

  const createConnection = (mongoClient, dbConnection) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        if (dbConnection) {
          console.log('===== Cached Connection =====');
          resolve(dbConnection);
        }
        console.log('===== New Connection =====');
        let dbPool = await connectDatabase(mongoClient);
        resolve(dbPool);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  };

const closeDbConnection = conn => {
  if (conn) {
    return conn.close();
  }
};

module.exports = {
  connectDatabase: connectDatabase,
  createConnection: createConnection,
  closeDbConnection: closeDbConnection
};
```

**Handler code**

```
let admin = require('./lib/admin');
let helper = require('./lib/helper');
let connection = require('./lib/connection');
let mongo = require('mongodb');
let mongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;
let cachedDb = null;

let createUser = async (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  cachedDb = await connection.createConnection(mongoClient, cachedDb);
  admin.createUser(cachedDb, helper.parseEvent(event), callback);
};
```

I'm using a global variable **`cachedDb`** to store the database connection but
each and every time I make a request it logs `===== New Connection =====` any idea how to achieve this.
Is there a better way to handle this?.

Comment: I think just check `if (dbConnection)` instead of `if (dbConnection && dbConnection.isConnected(dbName))`, what is the `dbName`, maybe it is a invalid options of `isConnected`

Comment: @hoangdv I did that too but `dbConnection` is alway null I don't know why

Answer (score 3):

The approach I like using here is a singleton class, like this:

```
export default class MyMongoConnection {
    static instance;

    static getInstance() {
        if (!MyMongoConnection.instance) {
            MyMongoConnection.instance = MyMongoConnection.createInstance();
        }
        return MyMongoConnection.instance;
    }

    static createInstance() {
        // Do whatever you need to create the instance
    }
}
```

So you import MyMongoConnection anywhere and just ask for the instance using .getInstance(), if it exists, it reuses it.

Hope this helps.